# Multiple orderBy() in Firestore Query Produces Error

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I want to query Firestore db and order by two fields. [Official docs](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/samples/firestore-query-order-multi) suggest I can simply combine the orderBy statements via `orderBy('field1').orderBy('field2')` but when I run similar code, I get the following error in console:

`Project.js:62 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: (0 , firebase_firestore__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.orderBy)(...).orderBy is not a function`

My code:

```
const projectRef = doc(db, 'projects', projectId)
const docSnap = await getDoc(projectRef)

if(docSnap.exists()) {
    const imagesInfoRef = collection(db, 'projectGalleryImages')
    const imagesInfoDocsSnapshot = await getDocs(query(imagesInfoRef, where('project', '==', projectRef), orderBy('displayOrder').orderBy('createdOn')))
    imagesInfoDocsSnapshot.docs.map(imageInfo => {
        const imageRef = ref(storage, `project/${projectId}/images/${imageInfo.fileName}`)
        loadImageURL(imageRef)
    })
}
```

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing the older namespaced syntax with the newer modular syntax. In the latter, each `orderBy` call is a standalone instruction:

```
query(imagesInfoRef, 
  where('project', '==', projectRef),
  orderBy('displayOrder'), //  comma here, instead of a dot
  orderBy('createdOn')
)
```